# I'm making a trim wheel using a rotary encoder for flight simulation. Should I have the Joystick library use button presses or make it an axis?

Tags: arduino-leonardo, rotary-encoder, joystick

Title says the majority of it. I'm looking to make a trim wheel for flight sim using a rotary encoder, the Joystick library and an Arduino Leonardo. I wasn't sure if it would be better to make it a button press or have it be an axis, possibly the Rx, Ry, or Rz axis.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you not the one that knows what you want?

Comment: As you build that project, it is up to you to decide, wether you want to control trim via a joystick or button presses.

Comment: @jsotola I had an idea of what I thought would be best, but I wasn't sure if anyone thought differently. Thanks though!

Comment: @chrisl I had an idea of what I though would be best, but I wasn't sure if anyone thought differently. Thanks though!

Comment: `what I thought would be best` ... yes, it is your job to define what `best` means ... nobody else can tell you what is good for you ... and nobody else's opinion is relevant unless you ask a technical question